# convert IntPtr to bitmapimage

Tags: c#, wpf, image, intptr

I use twain_32 for the scan and in  `twainLib.TransferPictures` use `DibToBitmap.FormHDib(hbitmap)` to get a `bitmapsource` from `IntPtr` but I want a `bitmapimage`.

I want to convert the `IntPtr` `bitmapsource` to `bitmapimage` directly instead to make it a `bitmapsource` then a `bitmapimage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Bitmap Constructor Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14.aspx)

```
Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, Stride, PixelFormat, bitmapSource);
```

Comment: this will be a bitmap not a bitmapImage

Comment: A bitmap is actually a bitmap image since it inherits the image class. Once you have the bitmap you can do anything with the image like [save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx), set it to an Picture box / Image object etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
      [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
      private static extern IntPtr GlobalLock(IntPtr hMem);

        [DllImport("GdiPlus.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern int GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib(IntPtr pBIH, IntPtr pPix, out IntPtr pBitmap);
                public static Bitmap BitmapFromDIB(IntPtr pDIB)
                {
                    IntPtr pPix = (IntPtr)((int)pDIB + 40);
                    IntPtr pBmp = IntPtr.Zero;
                    int status = GdipCreateBitmapFromGdiDib(pDIB, pPix, out pBmp);
                    MethodInfo mi = typeof(Bitmap).GetMethod("FromGDIplus", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { pBmp });
                    if ((status == 0) && (pBmp != IntPtr.Zero)) return bmp;
                    else return null;
                }

 //   ******
    case TwainCommand.TransferReady:
    {
     ArrayList pics = tw.TransferPictures();
     IntPtr img = (IntPtr)pics[i];
     PicForm newpic = new PicForm();
     var ptrLocked = GlobalLock(img);//lockedptr to image
     newpic.pBox.Image = BitmapFromDIB(ptrLocked); 
     newpic.MdiParent = this;
     int picnum = i + 1;
     newpic.Text = "Picture " + picnumber.ToString();
     newpic.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about `BitmapSource` and your question is tagged with `WPF`, here's a way to avoid using `System.Drawing.Bitmap`:

```
Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(imagePointer, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, 
    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

You'll need to use `System.Windows.Interop`.